# Работа с двусвязным списком. Поиск максимального элемента

Tags: c++

Структура двусвязного списка:

```
struct list
{
    int inf;
    list* next;
    list* prev;
};
```

Функция с ошибкой:

```
int find_max(list* head, int size)
{
    list* ptr; //вспомогательный указатель
    ptr = head;
    int max = ptr->inf; //даем значение максимуму
    //по всему списку
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (max < ptr->inf) max = ptr->inf;
        ptr->next;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделано неправильно, так как всегда возвращается 1 элемент списка.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за ответ, предупреждения компилятор не показывает. Как сделать иначе, чтобы работало?

Comment: Раз не показывает, значит предупреждения выключены. Стоит включить.

Comment: Как вы думаете, что делает `ptr->next;`?

Comment: *Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделано неправильно* - игнорируете предупреждения компилятора, обращаетесь с двухсвязным списком, как с массивом. Не пробуете самостоятельно отладить прежде, чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , по сути переносит указатель, но нет. Поняла свою ошибку. Нужно писать ptr = ptr->next; чтобы перейти к следующему элементу, если я верно понимаю. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int find_max(list* head)
{
    list* ptr; //вспомогательный указатель
    ptr = head;
    int max = ptr->inf; //даем значение максимуму
    //по всему списку
    while (ptr)
    {
        if (max < ptr->inf) max = ptr->inf;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return max;
}
```